# how to set html form action when put website into production

Tags: html, flask, frontend, backend

I am a medical researcher and not offical programmer. So sorry for my dummy question. I am doing research about melanoma and would like to make my model public online. So I wrote a website and flask backend. Part of them looks like this:

```
    #html sample    
    <form id="upload_form" action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/melanoma" method="POST">
    </form>

    #flask sample
    @app.route('/melanoma', methods=['POST'])
```

They worked well in localhost.  I have a Window server and public IP. Then I put them into production but things went wrong.My question is how should I set action url of my form and route location of flask.

I know this is quite basic question. Please don't judge me.
Apprecite any help.

Answer (score 1):

If your front-end (the HTML file) is used by Flask too, then you can write

```
<form id="upload_form" action="melanoma" method="POST">
</form>
```

You don't need to specify `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`.

The form's action will be `your-domain/melanoma`.